# How to correctly implement Keras's fit_generator on multiple datasets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-processing, conv-neural-network

I am having a problem implementing Keras's fit_generator function. I have followed the Keras documentation and numerous other documentation online. But I can't seem to get this thing to work.

When I run the fit_generator, it is not throwing an error. I could tell that something is running in the background since my GPU usage on my task manager skyrockets to 70% processing. However, there is no text/verbose that says that the batches are being processed for my convolutional neural network.

#### This is my model

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=80, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(180, 180, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=60, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.2))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Dense(units = 40, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 20, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=5270, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

#### This is my batch generator

I have six hdf5 files that I want to loop through that each contain 40,000 images. They are already formatted as Numpy arrays. I am yielding a batch size of 20 each time.

```
def train_generator():
    counter = 1
    batch_size = 20

    while True:

        # Create arrays to contain x_train and y_train. There are six of these files in total, so 40000*6 = 240,000 items in the entire training set.
        # 240,000 images for each epoch
        h5f = h5py.File('x_train' + str(counter) + 'catID.h5','r')
        pic_arr = h5f['dataset'][0:40000]

        h5f = h5py.File('y_train' + str(counter) + 'catID.h5','r')
        cat_arr = h5f['dataset'][0:40000]
        h5f.close()

        # Since training size for first dataset is 40,000 and batch_size is 20, loop 2000 times because 40000/20 = 2000 
        for i in range(1,2001):
            if (i == 1):
                x_train = pic_arr[0:batch_size]
                y_train = cat_arr[0:batch_size]

                index = batch_size
                yield (x_train, y_train)
            else:
                x_train = pic_arr[index:index + batch_size]
                y_train = cat_arr[index:index + batch_size]

                index += batch_size
                yield (x_train, y_train)

        del pic_arr
        del cat_arr
        counter += 1
```

#### Fitting my model

When fitting my model with my generator, I know that my GPU is processing the data; I've got an NVIDIA GTX 1070. But there is no verbose/text displayed when running this code below. I also tried running without GPU, but still no luck. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow as tf

# This is used to store the best weights for our trained model.
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights_bestcatID.hdf5', 
                           verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

# steps_per_epoch=12000 because --> 240,000 (total samples) / 20 (batch size) = 12000 
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    model.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=12000, nb_epoch=4, verbose = 1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Comment: What happen when counter > number of files?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I tried running this same code again and it worked... If anyone needs to reference how to implement Keras's fit_generator, the above works.

Comment: Just had to remove the parentheses in the yield statements.